# Highcharts graph remove existing ticks in interval on a category (x-axis)

Tags: highcharts

I have a live graph that updates every x time. Included below is an image using a dummy variable. What I would like is for Highcharts to only label the first, middle, and last. Or anything to where I don't spam my graph label with ticks.

[image]

Presently my xAxis looks like so:

```
xAxis: {
    crosshair: true,
    type: "categories",
    categories: xaxis
},
```

Nothing out of the ordinary. I have tried adding a tickInterval, however, that does not really solve the issue over the long run. Essentially what I need is the opposite of a tickInterval, where ticks are removed after a certain interval. Not unlike the datetime API that highcharts currently has. The difference here is that this data cannot be generated by myself, but by an API that I am using, which spits out the as-shown x-axis label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a while, in case there is too much xAxis labels displayed on a chart, the number of them is automatically reduced (the first example). Although, if you want, you can use couple of solutions. The best way, would be to use `tickPositioner` to display only the first, the middle and the last labels and format them using `Highcharts.dateFormat` inside `xAxis.labels.formatter` (the second example). You could also set bigger `step` of `xAxis.labels` (the third example).

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositioner
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Highcharts.dateFormat
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.step

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/vxjdwer7/ - default behaviour
http://jsfiddle.net/30t45zvq/ - using tickPositioner
http://jsfiddle.net/6g9uvokL/ - using step

Comment: Thanks. the only lingering issue here is that I would like this behavior applied to categories. So if I had `[apple, bear, banana, orange, etc, etc]` as x-values I would like to only show the first, middle, and last category values. Your tickPositioner example uses datetime.

Comment: Simply change xAxis.type to `category` and use categories array. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/307a2o3v/.

Comment: One thing I noticed from your recent example at `http://jsfiddle.net/307a2o3v/` is that if I enable zoom, the x-axis stays the same and does not correspond to the portion of the chart I'm zoomed into. For instance, if I zoom into an area that's in between Apple and Banana, I won't see bear.